# swap the item in the list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 5 item in the list.I want to keep first and last item in same position and need to swap the item list as slider.

```js
var i=0;
$('.flex-next').click(function(){
   i=i+2;
   alert(i);
  $(".thumbnailIcon li:eq(1)").before($(".thumbnailIcon li:eq(i)"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slider">
    <div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
    <ul class="thumbnailIcon">
      <li>left</li>  
      <li class="69">1</li>
      <li class="233">2</li>
      <li class="299">3</li>
      <li>right</li>  
    </ul> 
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
    <div class="node_id"><span>222</span></div>
    <ul class="thumbnailIcon">
      <li>left</li>  
      <li class="69">1</li>
      <li class="233">2</li>
      <li class="299">3</li>
      <li>right</li>  
    </ul> 
    </li>
    <a href="#" class="flex-next">click<a>
    <li class="parent">
    <div class="node_id"><span>333</span></div>
    <ul class="thumbnailIcon">
      <li>left</li>  
      <li class="69">1</li>
      <li class="233">2</li>
      <li class="299">3</li>
      <li>right</li>  
    </ul> 
    </li>
```

I want to change the position of all the  thumbnailIcon list item in the position as shown. onload [0,1,2,3,4] (working),on click I want to change the position of the list as [0,3,1,2,4] and next click [0,2,3,1,4] .I want to change the list as given above in click function.Is it posible do it.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: i will add snippet

Comment: I think this kind of functionality can be achieved with bootstrap.
Bootstrap provides classes like col-sm-push-* or col-sm-pull-*.

These classes move content to the right or left as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code can help you.

```js
function changeAllOrder(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
   var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
  
    //normal
  $(secondLi).before(fourthLi);
  });
}

function changeSingleOrder(){
 event.preventDefault();
 var thumbnails = $(event.currentTarget).prev().find("ul");

   var fourthLi = $(thumbnails).find("li:nth-child(4)");
    var secondLi = $(thumbnails).find("li:nth-child(2)");
 
  //reversed
 $(fourthLi).after(secondLi);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slider">
<div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li class="69"><img> 1</li>
  <li class="233"><img> 2</li>
  <li class="299"><img> 3</li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>
<li class="parent">
<div class="node_id"><span>2</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li class="69"><img>1</li>
  <li class="233"><img>2</li>
  <li class="299"><img>3</li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>
<a href="" onclick="changeSingleOrder()" class="flex-next">click<a>
<li class="parent">
<div class="node_id"><span>3</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left</li>  
  <li class="69"><img></li>
  <li class="233"><img></li>
  <li class="299"><img></li>
  <li>right</li>  
</ul> 
</li>
<input type="button" onclick="changeAllOrder()" value="Change Order" />
```

Comment: Is it posible to do it in reverse

Comment: @user3386779 The reversed logic is added to the anchor tag (link), the normal code is still on the button click.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like that:

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
$('#view').text(a.toString());

function changeArray() {
    // get the first and lest elements, and remove them from array
    var first = this.a[0]
    var last = this.a[this.a.length - 1];
    a = this.a.slice(1, this.a.length - 1);

    // manipulate the internal array
    a.unshift(this.a.pop());
    
    // restore the first and last elements
    a.unshift(first);
    a.push(last);
    
    $('#view').text(a.toString());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="view"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="changeArray()">change array</button>
```

Comment: can you make the fiddle